# "Reduce to" or "reduce by"?

Tags: british-english, writing

Can I use the verb *reduce* in the following way?

Also can anyone help me verify the whole sentence?

> The transmission overhead is reduced to more than 95%.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about this? What is this transmission etc? If you say 'reduced *to* 95%' it means it is now running at 95% of what it was. If you say 'reduced *by* 95%', it means it is now running at only 5% of what it was.

Comment: the transmission overhead at t=0 is about 200K and at t=1 is about 10K

Answer (score 2):

Your comment that *the transmission overhead...is about 200K and (now)...is about 10K* would seem to indicate that it has been **reduced BY 95%**.

Comment: Yes. In fact, "total" = "reduced to" + "reduced by" (in percent).

Answer (score -1):

Regarding 'reduced to' or 'reduced by', there is an implicit context in case of 'reduced to'.    The sentence "The transmission overhead is reduced to less than 95%" sounds better than "The transmission overhead is reduced to more than 95%".  'reduced to more than 95%' is acceptable if 'transmission overhead' is normally or expected to be say 98%